# How do i make random letter from a string?

Tags: python

In python I want to know how to get random letter from string.

eg.

```
randomize("HELLO")
```

> ```
> returns "L"
> ```

Comment: use random.sample

Comment: @e4c5: you mean `random.choice()`, surely.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are right, if only one item is being picked, choice is a lot better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
return (random.choice(string))
```

Comment: Wow that was easy. Thanks!

Comment: Strings are sequences, there is **no need** to turn them into a list first, `random.choice(string)` works as is. And the latter is trivially done with `list(string)`, no need to write an explicit loop. And `return` is a statement, not a function, just use `return random.choice(string)`.